# Semi-continuous fields of C*-algebras having dimension one on a dense set

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, c-star-algebras

Given a Hausdorff, locally compact space $X$, let us consider a semi-continuous field $\{A_x\}_{x\in X}$ of C*-algebras over $X$, such that $A_x$ is one-dimensional for every $x$ in a dense subset $D$ of $X$, while the dimension of $A_x$ is bigger than one for $x$ in $X\setminus D$.  I can cook up some simple examples in which $X\setminus D$ is a discrete set but I am wondering how much more complicated can this be.  Precisely, I'd like to know:

> Is it possible to build an example in which $D$ fails to be open.

Comment: @NikWeaver,  I am using Dixmier's definition of continuous fields of C*-algebras.  Note that this does not imply local triviality!

Answer (score 2):

After talking to a friend I learned the following counter example to my own question.

Consider the topological space $X$ shown below and let $\pi$ be the vertical projection onto $[0,1]$.  We may then view $C[0,1]$ as a subspace of $C(X)$ by means of the injective homomorphism
  $$
  f \in C[0,1] \mapsto f\circ\pi \in C(X).
  $$
  Clearly $C[0,1]$ is contained in the center of $C(X)$, so one may write $C(X)$ as the algebra of sections of some semi-continuous field $\{A_x\}_{x\in [0, 1]}$ of C*-algebras.  One may then show that $A_x$ is one dimensional if and only if $x$ is not a diadic rational (in which case $\pi ^{-1}(x)$ is a singleton).

[image: Comb]

Comment: Are you not requiring that the map $x \mapsto \|a(x)\|$ be continuous?

Comment: @NikWeaver, you are right.  My original motivation, and in both my original question and my answer I indeed mean semi-continuous.  I'll wait for your feedback before perhaps editing both.

Comment: Oh, I see.  The problem makes more sense now!

Comment: Thanks to @NikWeaver for pointing out my initial confusion with the notions of "continuous" vs "semi-continuous" fields.  Bioth my question and answer have already been edited accordingly.